# How to get all the elements from the .ifc file?

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

I would like to Extract all the elements from the IFC file.
here is my code snippet

`var allElements = model.Instances.OfType<IfcBuildingElement>().ToList();`

from the above code, I can extract all walls, windows, etc
but my IFC file also contains Flow fitting, flow segment, etc. can you please guide me how I can extract these elements as well
here is my IFC file snippet

```
#800=IFCFLOWSEGMENT('2n8o7Tjz5F1hq6D4q35mMw',#42,'Rund:Luftkanal - T-St\X\FCck:7596625',$,'Rund:Luftkanal - T-St\X\FCck',#760,#784,'7596625');
#1123=IFCFLOWSEGMENT('2n8o7Tjz5F1hq6D4q35mMC',#42,'Oval:Luftkanal - Stutzen:7596647',$,'Oval:Luftkanal - Stutzen',#1049,#1119,'7596647');
#1895=IFCFLOWFITTING('2n8o7Tjz5F1hq6D4q35mJZ',#42,'Luftkanal - Sattelstutzen oval:Standard:7596808',$,'Luftkanal - Sattelstutzen oval:Standard',#1894,#1888,'7596808');
#3728=IFCFLOWFITTING('2n8o7Tjz5F1hq6D4q35mJu',#42,'Luftkanal - Bogen oval Segment:Standard:7596819',$,'Luftkanal - Bogen oval Segment:Standard',#3727,#3721,'7596819');
```

Comment: use `OfType<T>` with the right class/interface ... there is nothing connected with your ifc library it just `Enumerable.OfType` ... all you need to do is check library reference and find right interface/class and use it like you use `IfcBuildingElement`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is it possible to get all element classes/Interfaces which are exist in the IFC files?

Comment: *get all elemen* and what is `model.Instances`  ... again ... read the docs ... it you wouldn't you will never become a programmer

Comment: You're using the xbim toolkit libraries - you should probably state that for the wider audience. The issue is that IfcFlowTerminals are not subclasses of IfcBuildingElement in the IFC schema. Recommend you get familiar with the specifications: https://standards.buildingsmart.org/MVD/RELEASE/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/RV1_2/HTML/link/ifcflowterminal.htm

Answer (score 0):

In the [xbim](https://docs.xbim.net/) library, [OfType<T>()](https://docs.xbim.net/XbimDocs/html/39c51874-90ba-4541-0584-ca04bb10b59e.htm) filters the model instances, returning those that implement the type, by building a query against the underlying model store.

Your code is enumerating all instances that are `OfType<IfcBuildingElement>()`. i.e. you're filtering out everything but a small hierarchy of the building model's graph.

An [IfcBuildingElement](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/MVD/RELEASE/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/RV1_2/HTML/link/ifcflowterminal.htm) is defined as *all elements that are primarily part of the construction of a building, i.e., its structural and space separating system. Building elements are all physically existent and tangible things* - i.e. Walls, Windows, Beams etc. but **not** Flow Fittings/Segments (which are under IfcDistributionElement)

If you want to get all physical elements in a model just identify the appropriate ancestor in the hierarchy. I'd start with [IfcProduct](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/MVD/RELEASE/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/RV1_2/HTML/link/ifcproduct.htm), or [IfcElement](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/MVD/RELEASE/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/RV1_2/HTML/link/ifcelement.htm). If that's too broad you can always union together multiple IEnumerables.

If you don't use the `OfType<T>()` filter on model.Instances you'll really get everything in the model, which includes lots of abstract concepts such as relationships, representation etc.